# Accessing the outer instance of a nested class using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, inner-classes, nested-class

In Java, I have an inner class that has a native method:

```
public class A {
    class B {
        public native void foo();
    }
}
```

The native method is implemented in JNI:

```c++
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL A_0024B_foo(JNIEnv* env, jobject b);
```

Obviously the native function has access to `B.this`; it was passed in as `b`. How do I get access to `A.this`, the enclosing outer instance of `A`?

Answer (score 2):

Using javap, I'm pretty sure the answer is `this$0`

```
$ javac A.java
$ javap -s -p 'A$B'
Compiled from "A.java"
class A$B extends java.lang.Object{
final A this$0;
  Signature: LA;
A$B(A);
  Signature: (LA;)V
public native void foo();
  Signature: ()V
}
```

Note that if running on a unix-style command line you need the quotes to keep the $ from being interpreted as the start of a shell variable.

Also note (in case this comes up in someone else's search results) that the constructor for the inner class has an implicit first parameter of the outer class -- so if you want to construct one of these from native, you'll have to ask for the constructor that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is no jni support to access $this or whatever the variable is **actually** called, you could just pass B.this to the native function.

Comment: Well, the native function is being called externally, and I wouldn't want to make the caller do that (not to mention they could pass the wrong thing). I'm currently working around it by having another method in B that just returns `A.this`, and calling that from JNI, but I'd like to get rid of that